# Set a regex pattern to condition placing or removing spaces before or after a ) according to the characters that are before or after

Tags: python, regex

```py
import re

input_text = "((NOUN) )   ) de el auto rojizo, algo) ) )\n Luego ((PL_ADVB)dentro ((NOUN)de baúl ))abajo.) )."

input_text = input_text.replace(" )", ") ")

print(repr(input_text))
```

Simply using the `.replace(" )", ") ")` function I get this bad output, as it doesn't consider the conditional replacements that a function using regex patterns could, for example using `re.sub( , ,input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE)`

```
'((NOUN))   )  de el auto rojizo, algo)) ) \n Luego ((PL_ADVB)dentro ((NOUN)de baúl) )abajo.)) .'
```

The goal is to get this output where closing parentheses are stripped of leading whitespace's and a single whitespace is added after as long as the closing parenthesis `)` is not in front of a dot `.` , a newline `\n` or the end of line `$`

```
'((NOUN))) de el auto rojizo, algo)))\n Luego ((PL_ADVB)dentro ((NOUN)de baúl))abajo.)).'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just strip the preceding whitespaces before `)` with the following simple regex:

```
input_text = re.sub(r"\s*\)", ")", input_text)
print(repr(input_text))
```

---

```
'((NOUN))) de el auto rojizo, algo)))\n Luego ((PL_ADVB)dentro ((NOUN)de baúl))abajo.)).'
```

Comment: Excuse me, do you know how to make it so that if one of those parentheses is immediately followed by a letter then it leaves a space in between? For example `((PL_ADVB)dentro ).`  to `((PL_ADVB) dentro ).` ? I need use a similar pattern, but `re.sub(r"\)\w", ")", input_text)` ?

Comment: @Matt095, if you have additional conditions - they should be reflected in your main question

Comment: Sorry, just ask not to ask a similar question, since I forgot that case. Anyway, you are right

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern it should solve it

/(\s*)())(\s*)(?=[^\s])/g

This pattern will match a ')' that is followed by a non-whitespace character and remove any spaces before or after the ')'.

If you want to add spaces around a ')' instead of removing them, you can modify the pattern like this:

/(\s*)())(\s*)(?=[^\s])/g

Comment: Excuse me, do you know how to make it so that if one of those parentheses is immediately followed by a letter then it leaves a space in between? For example `((PL_ADVB)dentro ).`  to `((PL_ADVB) dentro ).` ? I need use a similar pattern, but `re.sub(r"\)\w", ")", input_text)` ?